# How can i post a image on the Facebook user feed using the Api or Sdk

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

Hallo I’m working on a C# console application that has to post a message and image to Facebook. I already have the first part working and for now the authentication token is not a problem. but I’m having a lot of trouble getting my program to upload any kind of media.

I would very much appreciate it if anyone could help me on this, I have been learning about the Facebook Api and Sdk for the last few days on my internship but I’m not really making progress.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
using Facebook;
using System;
using System.Dynamic;

namespace ApiHandlerFacebook
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            PostMessage();
            Console.WriteLine("\nPress the Enter key to exit the application...\n");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Terminating the application...");
        }

        private static void PostMessage()
        {
            //Fill the brackets with a access token to test the application
            //You can easily get a temporary token using the Graph Api Explorer from Facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/
            //But do make sure you have the "publish_actions" permission otherwise it wont work.
            string access_token = "ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE";

            dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
            parameters.message = "Test Message";
            parameters.subject = "test 123";
            parameters.link = "https://youtu.be/dQw4w9WgXcQ";
            parameters.picture = "http://b.vimeocdn.com/ps/588/58832_300.jpg";
            parameters.name = "Article Title";
            parameters.caption = "Caption for the link";
            parameters.description = "Longer description of the link";
            parameters.privacy = new
            {
                value = "SELF"
            };

            var client = new FacebookClient(access_token);
            client.Post("/me/feed", parameters);
            Console.WriteLine("Posted");
        }
    }
}
```

Edit 1:
To make it a bit more clear:

[This is what I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUl9c.png)

[This is what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QiMd.png)

Edit 2:
I still have some code I was experimenting with to post the image which does not work but maybe one of you know how to get it to work:

```
FacebookMediaObject media = new FacebookMediaObject
{
    FileName = "TestImage.jpg",
    ContentType = "image/jpeg"
};

byte[] img = File.ReadAllBytes("http://static.mnium.org/images/contenu/actus/Overwatch/Ocarine/D.va/d_va__by_guweiz.jpg");
media.SetValue(img);

parameters.source = media;
```

Comment: You can start by setting the client.Post result to a variable and look at it after the post and see what comes back.

var result = client.Post("/me/feed", parameters);

This could be a permissions issue...

Comment: I don’t think so, I got no error messages about permissions and to be sure I added a lot more permissions to my token that might have been necessary, but that did not change anything so I don’t know.

Comment: Whats the result from the client.post method? did you look at it?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images

Comment: @pmeyer the result of the first code can be seen in the **This is what I have** link of the first edit. That code works to post an link that uses and image as "button". but what I really want is what is shown in **This is what i want** link of the first edit, which is just an image that has been posted in the feed.

Comment: OK, according to the facebook developers documentation. If the image is smaller than 600 × 315 if will show as such, try uploading a bigger image. the image you are uploading is only 300 x 300.

Comment: @pmeyer I tested what you told me but it still showed up the same way (**This is what I have**). So that is not the problem, the image in "**This is what I have**" is actually a link and not really a photo, as in "**This is what I want**". what I would like to do is upload a photo the way I can do it as a user in Facebook itself. just an posted image in the feed.

Comment: @TheRWS96 Please update your code on the question and the "this is what I have" image to look at what you are actually doing.